# $watch ngModel not firing

Tags: angularjs

I have made a directive to handle file uploads, and it works when uploading files, but not so good when preloading data because the watch on the model is not giving me the expected results.

And those areis the relevant parts of the code:

http://codepen.io/sergio0983/pen/EyLwaQ?editors=1011

the part that is causing me a headache is this one:

```
<div ng-app = 'app' ng-controller = 'customCtrl'>

<file ng-model = 'doc' placeholder = 'modelEmpty' required></file>
<file ng-model = 'existingDoc' placeholder = 'modelNotEmpty' ng-required></file>

<div>
```

**JS**

```
  app.controller("customCtrl", function($scope){
      $scope.existingDoc = "filename.jpg"
  })

app.directive("file", function($parse){
    return{
        restrict:"E",
        require:"?ngModel",
        scope:{
            ngModel:"="
        },
        transclude:true,
        .....
        link:....

        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newVal, oldVal){
           console.debug(newVal, oldVal);
        });
    }
 });
```

Inside this watch, I want to do some initialization when the model has a value set, but I always get "undefined", "undefined" for the newVal and oldVal. Probably I´m missing something basic, but couldn´t find anything.

Besides, calling $setViewValue doesn´t even fire the watch: maybeI misunderstood something, but I thought that $setViewValue changed the model value, and so, I expected it to fire the $watch.

Could someone explain me how is supposed all that stuff to work?? I´m clearly missing something.

Comment: If you want to tie into `ngModel` (and all its formatters/validators/etc.) you have to use the `controllers` (4th positionally I believe) argument in the directive `link` function (assuming you're using a `link` function) and access the [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) argument of the link function.  If you simply want to pass data back and forth you can use `=` and do a watch.  You should simply need to watch the string `'ngModel'`, though, not `attrs.ngModel`.

Comment: something like that? ctrl.$setViewValue(scope.file); I do, but it doesn´t fire the $watch

Comment: Post the part "watch the string"  as an answer... ^^

Comment: Well, `$watch` as `ngChange` directive don't fire because they have no support for `inputs type="file"`.

Comment: I´m not using ngChange, but adding an event listener to the element inside the link function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to two-way bind data in a directive, using `=` in the `scope` and a `$watch` in the link function is all you need to do (watch the name of the variable on the scope):

```
scope.$watch('ngModel', function (/* ... */) { /* ... */ });
```

It might be confusing to consumers of your directives if `ng-model` is the name of the attribute, so I'd recommend choosing a different name (preferably that isn't prefixed with `ng-`).

Comment: Well, angular syntax is still a bit confusing to me, and still don´t fully know where/how to use things (besides, there are a lot of examples that induce to confusion, specially realtive to ngmodel). But in this case, there is a reason to use ngModel (I think, please correct me if I´m wrong). It´s supposed to work as an input, and thus, use the same validators of an input (for example, I have a serializer tool that reads the components of a form to build a multipart request, and I think I couldn´t do it without binding to ngModel).

Comment: @sergio0983: I think the only thing syntactical about Angular 2 is its expressions, but that's mostly JavaScript-based; everything else is HTML JavaScript with Angular's API.  If you wanted to tie into form validation, ngModel would be the recommended approach.  I would read the entire documentation around forms, validation, ngModel, etc. and then read some blogs, going back and forth until the API makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it is also tied to angular form validation, this file directive I made can be in a form, and can be required. Thank you.